# Amazon Cognito login approach and token validation?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, web-applications, amazon-cognito

I am reading lot of cognito documentation but the thing which is confusing is the limited documentation for build Hybrid applications(cordova mobile app).

This is my understanding so far:

I can develop my own sign-in and signup screens but use the cognito user pools as a backend authentication datastore.

or I can simply plug Cognito hosted webUI for sign-in, sign up.

1) If I have to use my own, I would have to use the Amazon cog SDK API to authenticate a user, validate email during signup etc .

2) If I need to use the hosted pages from amazon, I would need to configure it to redirect to my applications homepage.

probably follow this link -->> ?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-configuring-app-integration.html

Once the user is authenticated ,I would need to create session for logged-in user, decrypt the token which is a JWT to fetch all details about the user like user_name, etc & then tie this user to the same session. 
When the user clicks on any other link in my web application, my authentication filter will need to check if the current session had any valid token and validate it. Question is how do I validate that the token in the cookie is the one which is valid and not expired. which API can be used to check if the token is a valid token.Would I need to go to cognito eveytime?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use Cognito SDKs to validate the token before you serve your resources. The SDK methods to verify the token will ensure that the token has not expired, the user belongs to the app, and to the specific user pool that is allowed access to your resources.

You can find more here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html